# Capitalize the first letter of first word inside the brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to capitalize the first letter of each string inside the brackets...

If we have this string:

```
const text = 'This [forest or jungle] is [really] beautiful';
```

The desired result would be `'This [Forest or jungle] is [Really] beautiful'`

So far:

I have the capitalize function:

```
function capitalize(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

And here we have this regex code to select string inside the brackets:

```
/(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])/g
```

Please help

Comment: Each word inside brackets or just the first one? Or, do you mean you can match all you need with `/\[[a-z]+]/g` regex?

Comment: First word actually.. I missed that point...thanks

Comment: `text.replace(/(?<=\[)[a-z](?=[^\][]*])/g, (x) => x.toLocaleUpperCase())`. Or can there be any Unicode letter? Like `łąka`? Maybe `/(?<=\[)[^\][](?=[^\][]*])/g`?

Comment: You already have the match `text = text.replace(/(?<=\[).*?(?=\])/g, m => m.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + m.slice(1));` just put the code of `capitalize` in the callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
text = text.replace(/(?<=\[)[a-z](?=[^\][]*])/g, (x) => x.toLocaleUpperCase())
// OR
text = text.replace(/(?<=\[)\p{Ll}(?=[^\][]*\])/gu, (x) => x.toLocaleUpperCase())
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5yiYua/1)/[regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/5yiYua/2). *Details*:

- `(?<=\[)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with a `[` char
- `[a-z]` - a lowercase ASCII letter
- `\p{Ll}` - any Unicode lowercase letter
- `(?=[^\][]*\])` - a positive lookahead that requires any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]` immediately to the right of the current location.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = 'This [forest or jungle] is [really] beautiful';
console.log( text.replace(/(?<=\[)[a-z](?=[^\][]*])/g, (x) => x.toLocaleUpperCase()) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern already have the match, and you can omit the parenthesis for the capture group. Then you can use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and use the `capitalize` function as the callback.

Example using your slightly modified pattern without the capture group:

```js
function capitalize(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
let text = 'This [forest or jungle] is [really] beautiful';
text = text.replace(/(?<=\[).+?(?=\])/g, capitalize);
console.log(text);
```

A bit more performant pattern could be using a negated character class

```
(?<=\[)[^\][]+(?=\])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJe3nd/1)

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=\[)` Assert a `[` at the left
- `[^\][]+` Match 1+ times any char except `[` or `]`
- `(?=\])` Assert a `]` to the right

Or with the negated character class

```js
const capitalize = s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);
let text = 'This [forest or jungle] is [really] beautiful';
text = text.replace(/(?<=\[)[^\][]+(?=\])/g, capitalize);
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

For the question above, try the following code:

```
let a = (x) => {let y = x.split('');y.forEach((z,i) => {if(z == '['){y[i+1]=y[i+1].toUpperCase()};});return y.join('');}
```

Split it into an array and convert the next finding word to uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

make e.g. use of string replacement and a regex which matches braces and captures the text in between them, like ... [`/\[([^\]]+)\]/g`](https://regex101.com/r/kCGe0G/1) ... which reads ...

- `/ ... /g` ... globally ...
- ... match an opening bracket `\[` ...
- ... then capture at least one character (or a sequence of it) which is not a closing bracket `([^\]]+)` ...
- ... then match an closing bracket `\]`.

```js
const textSample = 'This [forest or jungle] is [really] beautiful.';
const regXCapture = (/\[([^\]]+)\]/g);

console.log(
  textSample.replace(regXCapture, (match, capture) =>
    `[${ capture[0].toLocaleUpperCase() }${ capture.slice(1) }]`
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```